# How to tag aws iam users from another Terraform module?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

any ideas or techniques to tag iam users from specific module?

The Terraform allows get iam users as a data source, and also filter can be applied, like this:

```
data "aws_iam_users" "db_rw_users" {
   filter {
     name = "tag:db_rw"
   }
}
```

But I could not find any method to apply tags externally, without directly managing resource `aws_iam_user`.

No usable solution found.

Comment: Terraform either manages the resource or it doesnt, finding an already existing resource and wanting to modify it just isnt how terraform operates. you could use the awscli for this type of activity.

Comment: Actually my idea was to use iam groups for access segregation, e.g. db_ro and db_rw and db_adm and add developers to corresponding iam groups, but aws has non adjustable limit of how many iam groups the user can be member of, and this limit is really small of 10! So if we have like 10 database servers, it means that we need ar least multiple of 10 groups to manage this, especially if we want to have separate usernames for ro and rw.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it would be through [local-exec](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec?source=post_page---------------------------),  [custom data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) or [lambda invocation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_invocation).

Comment: it would be really interesting to have more details on lambda invocation approach. Local exec is already good idea with a combination of aws provider ignore_tags concept.